# Fulfilling IUserStore Dependency with Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I'm having some problems with getting unity to provide dependencies for my MVC controllers.

I want my ApplicationUser data and my business data in the same database and I am using code-first migrations with Entity Framework. To that end my DbContext inherits from IdentityDbContext and then implements an interface which represents my business data:

```
public class DealFinderDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IDealFinderDb
{
    public DealFinderDb() : base("name=DealFinderConnectionString", false)
    {
    }
    public IDbSet<Deal> Deals { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<SavedSearch> SavedSearches { get; set; }
    public static DealFinderDb Create()
    {
        return new DealFinderDb();
    }
}

public interface IDealFinderDb : IDisposable
{
    IDbSet<Deal> Deals { get; set; }
    IDbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    IDbSet<SavedSearch> SavedSearches { get; set; }
    int SaveChanges();
    DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
        where TEntity : class;
}
```

In my controller I need to be able to get the current user which means my controller has a dependency, not only on a IDealFinderDb but also on a UserManager. I understand that the best way to test this is to mock an IUserStore and pass that into the constructor of my controller. I have written the tests that mock both the IUserStore and the controller's HttpContext and these tests work as expected. This means my controller looks like this:

```
public class SavedSearchesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDealFinderDb dealFinderDb;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public SavedSearchesController(IDealFinderDb dealFinderDb, IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore)
    {
        this.dealFinderDb = dealFinderDb;
        this.userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var user = this.userManager.FindById(this.User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var usersSavedSearches = this.dealFinderDb.SavedSearches.Where(s => s.User.Id == user.Id);
        return this.View(usersSavedSearches);
    }

    // Snip unrelated action methods.

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.dealFinderDb.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

This seems fine but I am using Unity to provide implementations for these interfaces at run-time and this is where I'm stuck. My first attempt at my UnityConfig looks like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IDealFinderDb, DealFinderDb>();
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(
    new InjectionConstructor(typeof(DealFinderDb)));
```

...but the problem with that is I end up with a DbContext being instantiated twice leading to an error of "System.InvalidOperationException: 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.'" when I call `Add()` on any of my IDBSets in my DbContext I guess this is because unity is instantiating my DbContext twice.

So my next attempt was to ensure that only a single instance of DealFinderDb is created and that looks like this in my UnityConfig:

```
container.RegisterType<DealFinderDb, DealFinderDb>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IDealFinderDb, DealFinderDb>();
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(
    new InjectionConstructor(typeof(DealFinderDb)));
```

...but when `this.userManager.FindById()` is called in my controller I get the error "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.'". Obviously I could avoiding calling Dispose on my Context but this is bad as I assume means I am actually using the same DBContext instance for the entire life-cycle of my application.

What should I put in my UnityConfig to ensure that both the IDealFinderDb and IUserStore dependencies are satisfied and that only a single context is instantiated each time my controller is instantiated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I put in my UnityConfig to ensure that both the
>   IDealFinderDb and IUserStore dependencies are satisfied and that only
>   a single context is instantiated each my controller is instantiated?

You should use per-graph lifetime manager which is called `PerResolveLifetimeManager` in Unity:

```
container.RegisterType<IDealFinderDb, DealFinderDb>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
```

Answer (score 0):

According to best practice to software design pattern, you should always follow Singleton Pattern while creating database context and logger context and many other things as per business requirement if you feel there is a need for singleton object go for that and while using singleton pattern do take care of thread safety singleton if you are implementing threads.its so easy and for help, you can refer  MSDN, it has an implementation of the singleton.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx
Hope this helps.

Comment: I have read several articles about avoiding making a DbContext a singleton, specifically due to memory & lazy loading issues. I suppose lifetime management of DbContext is a pretty complex thing. I think I'd like to avoid making it a singleton at this point but thanks for the link.